# index is changing every time i'm clicking a button

Tags: jquery

http://gidzior.net/svg/pom01.html panel on the right is the '#right-panel li' and the red button is the 'div.save'

buttons from '#right-panel li' should open a window and button 'div.save' should close it and then '#right-panel li' should open it again

when i'm clicking button with number from 1 to 9, script put 0 befor number 1-9 and the index is 01,02,03 ..., when i'm clicking it again the index is 001, 002, 003,... and so on, how do I set the index remained the same all the time ?? 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09

```
//OPEN A WINDOW 
    $('#right-panel li').each(function(e){
        var i = $(this).index()+1;
        $(this).click(function(){
            if(i<=9){
                i = "0"+i;
            }
            $('#pom01par'+i+'WraperAbsolute').fadeIn("fast");
            $('#pom02par'+i+'WraperAbsolute').fadeIn("fast");
            $('#pom03par'+i+'WraperAbsolute').fadeIn("fast");
            $('#pom04par'+i+'WraperAbsolute').fadeIn("fast");
            $('#pom05par'+i+'WraperAbsolute').fadeIn("fast");
            $(this).css('background','#adff84');
            $('.par'+i+'table').css('background','#adff84');
            return false;
        });
    });


    // CLOSE A WINDOW
    $('div.save').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().fadeOut("fast");
    });
```

Comment: i is not a number, it is a string in your context.

Comment: @EvilP: It varies. It starts out as a number, then becomes a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem that jumps out at me is:

```
if(i<=9){
  i = "0"+i;
}
```

You are modifying the value of i;

Instead use another variable in the click function:

```
$('#right-panel li').each(function(e){
        var i = $(this).index()+1;
        $(this).click(function(){
            var this_i = i;
            if(this_i<=9){
                this_i= "0"+i;
            }
            $('#pom01par'+this_i+'WraperAbsolute').fadeIn("fast");
            $('#pom02par'+this_i+'WraperAbsolute').fadeIn("fast");
            $('#pom03par'+this_i+'WraperAbsolute').fadeIn("fast");
            $('#pom04par'+this_i+'WraperAbsolute').fadeIn("fast");
            $('#pom05par'+this_i+'WraperAbsolute').fadeIn("fast");
            $(this).css('background','#adff84');
            $('.par'+this_i+'table').css('background','#adff84');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define `i` in the scope of the `click(` function, or better yet- don't define it at all:

```
$(this).click(function(){
var iAsString = $(this).index()+1 + "";            
if($(this).index()+1<=9){
                iAsString = "0"+iAsString;
            }
```

Comment: how to write this condition to be true only for 01, 02, 03...09 ??

Answer (score 0):

I don´t sure about the error.

But I try make my own index.

Change

```
var i = $(this).index()+1;
```

by

```
var i = 1;
```

in the end of the loop put i++;

```
$('#right-panel li').each(function(e){
......
 i++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand why you are doing such a thing, but I come with a very short solution.
Try to modify the condition this way

```
if(i<=9 && i.length==1){
    i = "0"+i;
}
```

This way you're gonna check the value of `i` both as a number and as a string.

Comment: `length` is a property of a string, not a function. And a condition is written with two `=`, like `if (i.length == 1) i = "0"+i;`